# How to strech header across entire page using flexbox and use responsvise screenstate

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm mainly trying to stretch my navigation bar across the entire page using flexbox. I want the design to be responsive so that the layout stays the same for screen sizes between 640-1280 px.

I've read about similar questions here and tried to implement some answers but it doesn't seem to work.

My codepen (not allowed to change anything in the html part):

https://codepen.io/Noruas/pen/OeQNLy

```html
<div id="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Surf Co</h1>
    <p> Ripper nose open face tide!</p>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Surf</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>

    <section id="products">
      <article class="promote">
        <h2>Pearl Tri Fin</h2>
        <h3 class="date"><time>12 Apr, 2019</time></h3>
       <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531722569936-825d3dd91b15?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='longboard on a beach'>
        <p>Salt water clean flow, jumbled pearl tri fin. Set, urll fair-good shoulder high wetsuit tan. Vertical tide switch explosive muscle healthy float aquarium kick out double overhead whitewater. Ripper nose open face tide cranking WCT coil up rock-n-roll technique. Over head board epic fins foam claim sand bar Freddy P.. Air drop a-frame full rote rip tide layback daggers..</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Kook in da wa ripper</h2>
        <h3 class="date"><time>5 Apr, 2019</time></h3>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520443240718-fce21901db79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='surfer in water'>
        <p>Making it rain power hack forehand hook hack reef rash healthy float. Viscious ride tides courdoroy firing white water urll. Coffee stale fish DOH line-up stall above the lip epic cutties. Late chops fair full mad air reverse rights pitted freshie thick? Wax the stick good hollow spittin' frothed fat. Kook in da wa ripper in the bricks fun board ocean make the drop. Tight section Margaret River barreling <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6hoBp7Hk-A">Pipeline</a> psyching.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Kelp rocker elevator</h2>
        <h3 class="date"><time>1 Apr, 2019</time></h3>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501571190884-100604650072?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='wave breaking'>
        <p>Kelp rocker elevator drop heavy section <a href="https://vimeo.com/77483068">gnarley</a> a-frame. Turds in the lineup make the drop kook rip tide nice little layback hammer Taj Burrow top turn tossin' pizzas. Loc foam snap tagging full mad air reverse rad, grommet lines turds in the lineup. Dredging backside attack rock-n-roll Pipeline, buy my poster, rain John John Florence standing tall pipeline pit. Salt water forehand hook frontside stomps it, lay day fog tide tossin' pizzas. Rocker Kerrzy, over head indy, fin fair-good.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Vertical hook down the line</h2>
        <h3 class="date"><time>3 Apr, 2019</time></h3>
        <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1414490929659-9a12b7e31907?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='surfboard in sunset'>
        <p>Vertical hook down the line surfing, Pipeline ice cream headaches standing tall spit bottomed out wonky. Channel blonde rigs claim Kerrzy brah cheater5 coil up healthy float. Shallow ice cream headaches claim rail grab making the bottom turn cracking it closeout. Tri fin ride backhand attack round house cutty wobble viscious. Salt water wind swell fired up reef break tomb-stoning.</p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section id="classes">
      <h2>Classes</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Salt Water</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>Salt water wind swell fired up reef break tomb-stoning.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Indy Longboard</td>
            <td>1500</td>
            <td>Indy longboard late drop loc puff rusty transition ripping.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fish set</td>
            <td>12.50</td>
            <td>Fish set wave.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shaka</td>
            <td>199.99</td>
            <td>Twin keel feathering lip stick lay day shaka </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </section>

    <section id="story">
      <h2>Our Story</h2>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500520198921-6d4704f98092?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='collection of surfboars'>
      <p>Making the section whips one tide tubes inside position clean face Dane Reynolds. Drifting the tail monsters 360 tomb-stoning puff power hack, set wave surfline sets layback daggers. Set wave barny feathered lip J.O.B. poor-fair kook in da wa keyhole channel? Whitewater, combos keyhole pipeline wax the stick psyching whitewater Trestles speed tuck. Swell one wave set feathered lip split the peak cracking it one wave set coil up wobbly duck diving rows of white water, ripper. Round house cutty mellow inside position heavy slice Slates Pipeline big finner late leash!</p>
      <h2>White water</h2>      
<p>White water clamped finner standing tall nutty barnacle inner bar. New school shacks shack John John Florence full rote white wash. Pocket, Trestles waves in the bricks full rotation making it rain. Loose closed out hot glass skegs rail to rail. Top turn glazz socked in shred tube Taj Burrow digs rail, knee high. Socked in pitted critical waves send it. Standing tall channel quiver Jeffreys Bay legend claw hands.</p>
      <h2>Paddle</h2>
<p>Paddle out rank bro WQS keyhole feathering lip firing speed. Buy my poster stale fish blow tail nuggets of heaven foam, bumpy outer bar out the back. Smash crusty inside claim shred longboard cutties over the reef ending maneuver hit. Shaka free surf wetsuit tan swamped nose pick. Simpo drop knee pigdog bunny chow clipped kook pitted. Shutting down king of the peak carves layback daggers, full rotation shinner barn dog spitting barrels white water wall. Barreling late <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7woVTuN8k3c">Teahupoo</a>, turning on brutal wind swell point break crumbly lip priority fish. Ridin' the foam ball bottom turn pitter Kelly Slater double overhead fired up, coil up explosive.</p>
      <h3>Spitting barrels</h3>
<p>Pearl, closeouts jumbled fish hot glass, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPsORZun55g">Dane Reynolds</a> rip tide hot glass hallow muscle. Spitting barrels stomps it Bells tube sandbar barn dog squirt. Foam ball cartwheels shredded frothed tides tides layback daggers. Swamped Snapper Rocks barrels, fair-good tide switch fat make the drop hang 5, beat it kook. Cartwheels air game vertical layback hammer open face chops air reverse.</p>
    </section>

  </main>

  <aside id="newsletter">
    <h2>Newsletter</h2>
    <p>Sign up for our newsletter:</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="form-name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="Your name">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="form-email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="Your email">
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Set-up:</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="form-setup" value="quad"> Quad </label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="form-setup" value="single"> Singlefin </label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="form-setup" value="tri"> Trifin </label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit&rarr;">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Surf Co, 2019. Share the waves – no copyright or rights reserved. </p>
    <p>Images from <a href="https://unsplash.com">unsplash</a>. 
      Text by <a href="http://surfipsum.com">surfipsum</a>.</p>
  </footer>

</div><!-- end of container -->
```

```css
/* Global reset*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* My css (lägg egen css här) */
* {box-sizing: border-box; }
   body {
    max-width: autopx;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #99ebff;
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica);
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial);
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
   }
    #container {
        max-width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    #container > * {
        border: 3px solid #008fb3
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 3px solid #008fb3
    }
header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 175px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-color: #008fb3; 
  background: #008fb3;
  text-align: center; 
}

header h1{
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111111;
  border-color: #008fb3;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.8;
  font-size: 200%; 
  }

header p {
  color: #111111;
  opacity: 0.5;
  line-height: 0;
}

nav ul li a{
  grid-area: nav;
  background: #008fb3;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-color: #008fb3;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: center;

}

        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
          background-color: #99ebff;
        }

main a {
  color: #0099ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

main a:visited {
  color: #0033cc;
}
main {
  grid-area: content;
}

 #products {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}

.promote h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
}

#products h2 {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
 .date {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}


#products img{
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 45%;
  object-fit: contain;


}

#products p{
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
  }

#classes {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#classes h2 {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
}

#classes th{
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #008fb3;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#classes td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#classes tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
#classes tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: white;}
#classes tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#story, #newsletter{
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  }

#story h2 {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
}

#story h3, #newsletter h2 {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 125%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
}

#story p {
  height: auto;
  float: center;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
  }

#story img{
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:auto;
}

#newsletter {
  grid-area: bottombar;
}

#newsletter p{
  height: auto;
  float: center;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;

}
input[type=text]  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  resize: none;
  float: center;
}

label[for=form-name], label[for=form-email] {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
}

 #newsletter h3 {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  float: center;
}

input[type=Submit] {
  ine-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: center;
}

#newsletter ul li  {
 list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  }

        # newsletter li {
          float: left;
        }

        #newsletter li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        }


footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #008fb3; 
  height: 75px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-color: #008fb3; 
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

footer a {
  color: #111111;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

footer a:visited {
  color: #0033cc;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "nav"
    "li"
    "content"
    "bottombar"
    "footer";
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header  header"
      "nav     nav"
      "content content"
      " bottombar bottombar"
      "footer     footer";
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 640px, max-width: 1280px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header   header   header"
      "nav      nav         nav"
      "content  content content"
      "bottombar bottombar bottombar"
      "footer   footer   footer"
   }
   nav ul {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using CSS Grid in your code now. Possibly, you forgot to add the navigation element to your grid with using of

```
nav {
    grid-area: nav;
}
```

So if you add it, then navigation takes a full width, after that you can place navigation items inside as you wish.